# Getting error while adding web3 in react file

Tags: web3js, blockchain, javascript, react, web3-providers

I am completely new to web3 and react . I following a course to build a small project .I have been trying add a web3 instance in my main react file . I getting this error everytime .

> ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 2:16-43
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\SHORNA\lottery\node_modules\cipher-base'

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
> This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
> - install 'stream-browserify'
> If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
> resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
> enter code here

I cant figure our where I am going wrong .

whenever I add

> import web3 from './web3';
> this line in my app.js file I get above error

Here is my App.js file

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import web3 from './web3';

function App() {



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is web3.js file

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3=new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

export default web3;
```

Here is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "lottery",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {

    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
  

  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is a known problem of apps using Webpack 5, web3 package has certain dependencies, which are not present within the browser environment by webpack 5 and you need to polyfill.

You can follow this article from web3Auth, where they explain step by step how to solve this problem:

https://web3auth.io/docs/troubleshooting/webpack-issues#react

Hope it helps!

Comment: Still getting the same error !